# How can I handle null coalesce in this Linq query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hi I am using VB and getting an error in this.  I think I need to use null coalesce but I can't quite get that to work.  Here the issue is the DEVIATION object is null, which causes the crash.  I'd like to replace with empty string if that occurs.  How can I do that?  To be clear I do not want to filter results that are null, but I want to present the null results to user as blank.

```
Dim query = From a In db.ADCL_STANDARD_CHECK.AsEnumerable() Where (a.CHAMBER_STD_NO = mCHAMBER_STD_NO1) Order By a.ADCL_STANDARD_NO
                    Select New With {
                        Key .tStart = a.TSTART.Value.ToString("0.0000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) _
                    , .MSTART = a.MSTART.Value.ToString("0.0000E-00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) _
                    , .TEND = a.TEND.Value.ToString("0.0000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) _
                    , .MEND = a.MEND.Value.ToString("0.0000E-00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) _
                    , .dMdT = a.DMDT.Value.ToString("0.00000E-00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) _
                    , .DEVIATION = a.DEVIATION.Value.ToString("0.00%", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) _
                    , a.INCLUDE, a.ADCL_STANDARD_NO
                    }
        Me.dgvStandard.DataSource = query.ToList()
```

Comment: `.DEVIATION = If(a.DEVIATION?.Value?.ToString(...), String.Empty)`.

Comment: Thank you - this works:

                    , .DEVIATION = If(a.DEVIATION?.ToString("0.00%", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), String.Empty) _

Answer (score 1):

Temping the culture would tidy this up a chunk. You don't need line continuations either:

```vb
Dim ic = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Dim query = From a In db.ADCL_STANDARD_CHECK.AsEnumerable() Where (a.CHAMBER_STD_NO = mCHAMBER_STD_NO1) Order By a.ADCL_STANDARD_NO
                    Select New With {
                        Key .tStart = a.TSTART.Value.ToString("0.0000", ic),
                        .MSTART = a.MSTART.Value.ToString("0.0000E-00", ic),
                        .TEND = a.TEND.Value.ToString("0.0000", ic)
                        .MEND = a.MEND.Value.ToString("0.0000E-00", ic)
                        .dMdT = a.DMDT.Value.ToString("0.00000E-00", ic)
                        .DEVIATION = If(a.DEVIATION is Nothing, "", a.DEVIATION.Value.ToString("0.00%", ic)),
                       a.INCLUDE, a.ADCL_STANDARD_NO
                    }
        Me.dgvStandard.DataSource = query.ToList()
```